# What is the difference between StringIO and ByteIO?

Tags: python

What is the difference between StringIO and ByteIO? And what sorts of use cases would you use each one for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name says, `StringIO` works with `str` data, while `BytesIO` works with `bytes` data. `bytes` are raw data, e.g. 65, while `str` interprets this data, e.g. using the ASCII encoding 65 is the letter 'A'.

`bytes` data is preferable when you want to work with data agnostically - i.e. you don't care what is contained in it. For example, sockets only transmit raw `bytes` data.

`str` is used when you want to present data to users, or interpret at a higher level. For example, if you know that a file contains text, you can directly interpret the raw bytes as text.

Answer (score 3):

`StringIO` is for text. You use it when you have text in memory that you want to treat as coming from or going to a file. `BytesIO` is for bytes. It's used in similar contexts as `StringIO`, except with bytes instead of text.